# Somar registros com tipo_pgto em outra tabela

Tags: select, join, inner

Tenho 2 tabelas vinculadas pelo id e preciso somar um campo na tabela 2 agrupando através de um campo na tabela 1

```
-----TABELA 1-----
ID_tab1 - tipo_pgto

-----TABELA 2-----
ID_tab2 - ID_tab1 - valor_pago
```

Quero que me mostre a soma do valor pago que está na tabela 2 porem agrupado pelo tipo_pgto que está na tabela 1

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso:

```
select tipo_pgto, sum(valor_pago) from tab1 inner join
tab2 on tab1.ID_tab1 = tab2.ID_tab1_fk group by tipo_pgto
```

P.s.: *Adicionei o fk ali somente para que fique fácil de identificar que se trata de uma chave estrangeira vinda da tabela 1.*

Basicamente um select com inner join, unindo as duas tabelas, agrupando e somando pelo tipo de pagamento.

Veja funcionando no **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f831a/1/0)** (link atualizado)

**Referencias:**

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, já ajudou muito, mas se eu precisar do resultado da soma do tipo de pagamento 1 e tambem do tipo do pagamento 2 nesta consulta. O que quero é obter a soma dos pagamento a débito e a soma de pagamentos a credito, sendo que os pagamentos são inseridos na tabela 2 vinculados ao ID que esta na tabela 1 e nesta tabela 1 é que tem o campo identificando se é débito ou crédito.

Comment: Use `where tipo_pgto = tipodesejado` no final da da linha de código.

Comment: Ai que nao estou conseguindo, quero que na mesma consulta ele ja me mostre os dois resultados tipo: debito=1000,00 credito=1500,00 mas dentro do mesmo WHILE

Comment: @mcasite Cara o codigo já faz isso, veja o link no sqlfiddle. Está listando o tipo de pagamento e o total de cada um.

Comment: fiz com os dados tudo em uma unica tabela e consultava assim: SELECT  id_lc, data_pgto, SUM(CASE WHEN tipo='2' THEN valor_pago ELSE 0 END) AS totalR, SUM(CASE WHEN tipo='1' THEN valor_pago ELSE 0 END) AS totalD  FROM lc_movimento   WHERE ID='".$idEMP."' AND data_pgto > 0 GROUP BY CONCAT(MONTH(data_pgto),YEAR(data_pgto))     ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(MONTH(data_pgto), '-', YEAR(data_pgto)),'%m-%Y') ASC. Desta forma dentro do WHILE eu consegui pegar o total com TIPO 1 e 2 separados. Mas por motivos de ajuste na programação precisei dividir esta tabela em duas separando o campo tipo

Comment: @mcasite veja o link agora, se está da forma que você disse.

Comment: Resolvi assim: "SELECT lc_pagamentos.id_pg, lc_pagamentos.data_pgto, lc_parcelas.id_pa, lc_parcelas.id_fatura, lc_faturas.id_fa, SUM(CASE WHEN lc_faturas.tipo='2' THEN lc_pagamentos.valor_pago ELSE 0 END) AS totalR, SUM(CASE WHEN lc_faturas.tipo='1' THEN lc_pagamentos.valor_pago ELSE 0 END) AS totalD FROM lc_pagamentos, lc_parcelas, lc_faturas WHERE lc_pagamentos.ID='".$idEMP."' AND lc_pagamentos.id_parcela = lc_parcelas.id_pa AND lc_parcelas.id_fatura = lc_faturas.id_fa AND lc_pagamentos.data_pgto > 0 GROUP BY CONCAT(MONTH(lc_pagamentos.data_pgto),YEAR(lc_pagamentos.data_pgto))". Mto Obrigado

Comment: @mcasite seu problema é diferente da pergunta. Mas de fato a pergunta foi prontamente respondida. Seria interessante se você marcasse como respondida, assim, caso alguem com o problema da pergunta chegue até aqui, saberá que a resposta é a correta.